# Count Occurrences of a Value in a List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I don't know if I would generally store information this way, but this is how it's been presented to me.

Say I have a list of dictionaries that records the details of let's say UFO sightings, and looks like this:

```
aList = [{'country': 'japan', 'city': 'tokyo', 'year': 1995}, {'country': 'japan', 'city': 'hiroshima', 'year': 2005}, {'country': 'norway', 'city': 'oslo', 'year': 2005} ... etc]
```

I know how to count the number of occurrences in a list, but with dictionaries involved, I'm not sure how I'd go about it.

If I wanted to know which country had the most sightings of UFOs for example, how could I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) to count how many times each country appears in the list.  After that, you can use the `most_common` method to get the one that appears the most.  The code will look like this:

```
from collections import Counter
aList = [{'country': 'japan', 'city': 'tokyo', 'year': 1995}, {'country': 'japan', 'city': 'hiroshima', 'year': 2005}, {'country': 'norway', 'city': 'oslo', 'year': 2005}]

[(country, _)] = Counter(x['country'] for x in aList).most_common(1)

print(country)
# Output: japan
```

Below is a demonstration of what each part does:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> aList = [{'country': 'japan', 'city': 'tokyo', 'year': '1995'}, {'country': 'japan', 'city': 'hiroshima', 'year': '2005'}, {'country': 'norway', 'city': 'oslo', 'year': '2005'}]
>>> # Get all of the country names
>>> [x['country'] for x in aList]
['japan', 'japan', 'norway']
>>> # Total the names
>>> Counter(x['country'] for x in aList)
Counter({'japan': 2, 'norway': 1})
>>> # Get the most common country
>>> Counter(x['country'] for x in aList).most_common(1)
[('japan', 2)]
>>> # Use iterable unpacking to extract the country name
>>> [(country, _)] = Counter(x['country'] for x in aList).most_common(1)
>>> print(country)
japan
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a concise version:

```
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

aList = [{'country': 'japan', 'city': 'tokyo', 'year': 1995}, {'country': 'japan', 'city': 'hiroshima', 'year': 2005}, {'country': 'norway', 'city': 'oslo', 'year': 2005}]

countries = Counter(map(itemgetter('country'), aList))
print countries.most_common()

cities = Counter(map(itemgetter('city'), aList))
print cities.most_common()
```

**Output**

```
[('japan', 2), ('norway', 1)]
[('oslo', 1), ('hiroshima', 1), ('tokyo', 1)]
```